# authenticating mock user when testing in quarkus

Tags: quarkus

I'm trying to test a quarkus rest-endpoint which is secured with @RolesAllowed

```
...

@GET
@Path("{id}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
@RolesAllowed({ "APPLICATION_USER"})
public Response getFile(@PathParam(value = "id") String documentId, @Context UriInfo uriInfo)
...
```

The test case

```
@QuarkusTest
class DocumentResourceTest {

    @Test
    public void testDocumentEndpoint() {
        String documentId = "someId";

        given()
                .when().get("/documents/" + documentId)
                .then()
                .statusCode(200);
    }


}
```

How can i mock an authenticated user with role 'APPLICATION_USER' for my test case ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can inject a `SecurityIdentity` which you can then stub out with the relevant role using Mockito:

```
@QuarkusTest
public class DocumentResourceTest {

    @InjectMock
    SecurityIdentity identity;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        Mockito.when(identity.hasRole("APPLICATION_USER")).thenReturn(true);
    }

    @Test
    public void testDocumentEndpoint() {
        String documentId = "someId";

        given()
                .when().get("/documents/" + documentId)
                .then()
                .statusCode(200);
    }

}
```

You can of course move the stubbing call to your individual tests if you want to test a variety of different roles.

Note that you'll need to add the `quarkus-junit5-mockito` dependency for this to work:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
  <artifactId>quarkus-junit5-mockito</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I closed my browser tab and then reopened just to upvote your answer and comment here :)

Comment: Hey, this seems like the solution I was looking for. Unfortunately this does not work for me. Im using quarkus 2.7.5 and I do have quarkus-junit-mockito.

Is there anything else?

Answer (score 3):

A more convinient way to mock the security is to use Quarkus' security testing features:

https://quarkus.io/guides/security-testing#testing-security

Including

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-test-security</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

allows you to write

```
@Test
@TestSecurity(authorizationEnabled = false)
void someTestMethod() {
...
}

@Test
@TestSecurity(user = "testUser", roles = {"admin", "user"})
void otherTestMethod() {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the accepted answer, there is also this guide which explains how to deal with integration tests: https://quarkus.io/guides/security-oauth2#integration-testing

The first sentence there is:

> If you don’t want to use a real OAuth2 authorization server for your integration tests, you can use the Properties based security extension for your test, or mock an authorization server using Wiremock.

So I think the property based security extension could also work for you: https://quarkus.io/guides/security-properties